# Not able to build apk in Android Studio in by using android folder in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, apk

the issue I am facing is that I am not able to generate apk on android studio for the flutter.
[image]

I was running on 1.17.1 when I upgraded to 1.17.3 but some plugins had some issue so I have to downgrade since then this issue is on. I am not able to figure out why is it happening neither I am able to solve it. I have tried deleting the cache folder of flutter still no luck. Please help

Flutter build apk -v fails with this

[image]

Comment: what is the output of `flutter build apk -v` command?

Comment: @pskink attaching the output.

Comment: @pskink not able to copy it says to long

Comment: what about `flutter build apk`? does it say anything interesting?

Comment: I have added the image above please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216032/discussion-between-shivam-srivastava-and-pskink).